# Function only prints the correct statement for the last item in the list?

Tags: python, list, iteration

So the question asks:

> Write a function `is_member()` that takes a value (i.e. a number, string, etc) `x` and a list of values `a`, and returns `True` if `x` is a member of `a`, `False` otherwise. (Note that this is exactly what the in operator does, but for the sake of the exercise you should pretend Python did not have this operator.)

Here is my code:

```
list1 = type(list)
value = type(int)

def is_member(value, list1):
    for e in list1:
        if e == value:
            ans = 'Yes, the value ' + str(value) + ' is in the list'
        else:
            ans = 'No, the value ' + str(value) + ' is not in the list'
    return ans


print is_member(2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

I will only get the correct answer if i place value as the last item in the list, but every value before that even if it is in the list prints the second `ans` statement (No the value....).

How can I get it so that it prints the correct statement for any element in the list?

Comment: What is `list1 = type(list)` supposed to be doing?

Comment: You can (and should) [edit] your question if you have any more information to provide. Don't try to post code in comments.

Comment: Guess I don't need that do I? I wanted to make sure the program knows that list1 is always of type list.

Comment: python is dynamically typed, so that is unnecessary... actually when you do that, you are creating a variable of type `'type'` not of type `list`

Comment: to initialize an empty list, instead type `list1 = []`

Comment: so when i entered in the actual list in the print statement, Python automatically assumed that list1 is a list in the function, is this correct?

Comment: furthermore you don't even need to initialize those variables, as they are the inputs to your function `is_member`

Comment: @TheBaba yes, when you call: `is_member(2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])`, python automatically looks at the inputs between the brackets and determines what type of variable they should be converted into. As it reads the call, it will first encounter the 2, and say: _"this looks like a number but it has no decimal, so it must be an integer"_. Next it will find the square brackets and determine you are passing it a list. Then it will go through the same process to determine what type of variable is at each position in the list.

Answer (score 3):

```
def is_member(value, list1):
    for e in list1:
        if e == value:
            ans = 'Yes, the value ' + str(value) + ' is in the list'
            break
        else:
            ans = 'No, the value ' + str(value) + ' is not in the list'
    return ans


print is_member(2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

You were so close you just need to add a break.
The break statement stops the execution of the loop, and moves on to the next code available after the block. In this case your return statement

Important to note that setting setting ans to the same string on every iteration is unnecessary. However I wanted to modify your code into a working form with the least amount of modifications.

Comment: @theBaba http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_break_statement.htm isn't a bad reference for this topic.

Answer (score 2):

```
def is_member(value, list1):
    for e in list1:
        if e == value:
            return 'Yes, the value ' + str(value) + ' is in the list' 
    return 'No, the value ' + str(value) + ' is not in the list'
```

Would work as well as the other proposed answers.

Comment: "Misleading" proposes I'm leading him somewhere with those lines that he's not reached already. I simply was answering the question with the idea those lines where code for later changing. Edited them out none the less.

Comment: when the function is called, those variables are overwritten in the local scope, and will have the value given at call time, not the value given when they are initialized globally. this could lead to confusion on which value is being read and when

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make for a new programmer, and could be confusing if they've looked at some c or java examples where variables and their type must be declared.

Comment: I'm not arguing they were wrong, I'm in agreement there.

Answer (score 2):

You need to *return* in the for loop when you get a match or unless *value* is equal to the last element then you will always get ans set to what is in your else block even when getting a previous match:

```
def is_member(value, list1):
    for e in list1:
        if e == value:
            # return on any match
            return  'Yes, the value ' + str(value) + ' is in the list'
    # if we get here we had no match.
    return 'No, the value ' + str(value) + ' is not in the list'
```

You can also simplify to using *in* to test for *membership*:

```
def is_member(value, list1):
    if value in list1:
        return  'Yes, the value is in the list'
    return 'No, the value is not in the list'
```

Answer (score 0):

The question you've asked states

> "Write a function is_member() that takes a value (i.e. a number, string, etc) x and a list of values a, and returns True if x is a member of a, False otherwise.

```
def is_member(x, a):
    for list_item in a:
        if list_item == x:
            return True
    return False
```

So yes, whilst your code currently will only return the result based on whether or not the last value is equal to e (since you override `ans` every iteration), the entire return functionality is currently incorrect as per your requirements.